# Extern log4.properties file with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running my app with executable jar.

I have log4j.properties inside /resources folder

In prod I would like to override it and have it within external dir

How I could do that using Spring-Boot?

Comment: Adding _-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties_ to the command line should also work in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
-Dlogging.config=/path/to/log4j.properties
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Answer (score 11):

If you don't like to add command line arguments, you can make additional `application.properties` on the directory where you start the application. like:

```
# log4j configuration for product
logging.config=log4j-prod.properties
```

Then, this `application.properties` will override the `/resources/application.properties` and, the `log4j-prod.properties` will be used on the product environment. Please read more details on:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Answer (score 3):

try this:
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/log4j.properties -jar XX.jar

the -D configuration before the -jar configuration.
work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties` to the command line works in Spring Boot 1.5.6. Don't forget **file:** .