# Spring Boot environment aware log4j properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

I try to use environment aware log4j properties files in Spring Boot application, for example, log4j.properties is used for development and log4j-uat.properties for UAT environment as showed in picture.

[image: log files]

1. following [Extern log4.properties file with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072681/extern-log4-properties-file-with-spring-boot), I added logging.config=log4j-uat.properties to application-uat.properties and get exception said cannot find that properties file.

[image: Error log]

2. following https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1348, I added parameter when starting the application as java -jar logger-server.jar --spring.profiles.active=uat -Dlogging.config=classpath:log4j-uat.properties. However, it seems that the uat log4j properties is always overwritten by the default log4j properties.

Could anyone please advise me how to make Spring Boot pick up the log4j properties files for different environments?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: can you also paste exception trace

Comment: Yes, The exception stack has been added.

Comment: Did you already try setting the log4j.configuration property

`java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/log4j-uat.properties -jar logger-server.jar`? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7390591/6372139